# How do I make the ball on the curves run smoothly?

Tags: bezier-curves

A link to project file below

https://pasteall.org/blend/c79ccc9e7c1f4cb693b5df2509a6b8c7

[image]

[image]

I want to create an animation with a ball on 2 curved rails, I used rigid body and the ball is sliding but not smoothly, it looks like it's hitting little bumps on the way and it doesn't fully touch the rails object. but the rail is smooth and so does the sphere. what do I do?

Comment: what settings have you chosen for the ball? maybe try Shape > Sphere?

Comment: I already deleted the sphere and started over and I came to a result where the ball in inside of the rails and it's getting stuck whenever it hits the rings shown in the pictures

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @NirOfer - Moonboots is refering to the Rigid Body Collisions "Shape" setting on the sphere. It defaults to Convex Hull which will follow your mesh and is only an approximation of a sphere (hence the bumpiness). Setting the Rigid Body Collisions Shape to Sphere will handle your sphere as an actual smooth sphere and you should get a better result.

Comment: @RichSedman The first picture shows the situation after I set it the collision shape to sphere

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

I removed the rigid body you added and added it again to all your 3 objects because I wanted to change the settings. Copy the settings with the help of the GIF given below

[image]

**Step 2**

Change the end time in the cache settings to change the rigid body animation length because by default the rigid body animation always ends at frame 250 even if you change the animation length in the timeline. For example, if you set the value of the end frame under the cache settings to 'x' that means the rigid body animation will go up to frame number 'x'

[image]

**Result**

A small clip of the result.

[image]

**Step 3(optional)**

If you find your animation too slow or fast you can always change the speed in the scene properties like this.

[image]

Hope this helps and works for you :)

Comment: Thank you but the sphere is still floating at some point. Any way I can fix it?

Comment: actually, the sphere is not floating, it`s just flying across the curves because of that steep sudden declination

Comment: So there is nothing I can do about it to change it?

Comment: You just have to play with the rigid body settings until you get it right